# Cannot build cocos2d-x 4.0 cpp-test

Tags: visual-studio, cocos2d-x

Im just starting with cocos2d-x. I start by following the guide here. https://docs.cocos2d-x.org/cocos2d-x/v4/en/installation/Windows.html

Regarding prerequisites:

- Windows 7+ - **have windows 10**
- VS 2017+ - **have visual studio 2019**
- CMake 3.1+ - **installed latest**
- Python 2.7.5+, Python 2.7.10 reccomended , NOT Python 3+ - **installed Python 2.7.10**

Downloaded Cocos2dx v4 from github repo.

I run this command

```
python setup.py
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/90EjP.png

Then i run this command

```
cd COCOS2DX/tests/cpp-tests
mkdir win32-build
cd win32-build
cmake ..
```

Then I rebuild the generated solution and get this error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5ciQ.png

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -Tv142 -A Win32

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite make out details in picture, but you have failure accessing the Cocos library.

I got Cocos2d-x 3.17.2 working on VS2017 for cpp-test on Win10.
The generated Win32 solution for some reason did not include the cocos library.
I had to manually include libcocos2d, librecast, and libSpine projects in solution, fix dependencies and add libcocos2d resource to cpp-test project to make it compile.

As an aside, I am finding the test code quite helpful for showing how to accomplish things - just find a test doing what you are trying to do, and examine / step through the code to see how.

If you still have problems, perhaps ask for help on the Cocos2d-x forum:
https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/